# How not send email to original sender on ReplyToItem element in EWS

Tags: xml, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to reply to a message and remove sender of the original email message. In this example I have only CcRecipients element and I send it but original sender will get email too. How not send email to original sender ? Can I remove original sender ?

```
<m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">
      <m:Items>
        <t:ReplyToItem>
             <t:CcRecipients>
                <t:Mailbox>
                  <t:EmailAddress>example@gmail.com</t:EmailAddress>
                </t:Mailbox>
             </t:CcRecipients>
          <t:ReferenceItemId Id="MailId" ChangeKey="MailChangeKey" />
          <t:NewBodyContent BodyType="HTML">body message</t:NewBodyContent>         
        </t:ReplyToItem>
      </m:Items>
</m:CreateItem>
```

Comment: If you set the MessageDisposition to SaveOnly then save the message as a draft you can use UpdateItem to update the draft however you want and then use the SendItem operation to send the draft.

Comment: Thank you @GlenScales it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reply by definition includes the sender. If you just want a email, create just an email:

```
<m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">
  <m:Items>
    <t:Message>
      <t:Subject>Interesting</t:Subject>
      <t:Body BodyType="HTML">your original mail</t:Body>
      <t:ToRecipients>
        <t:Mailbox>
          <t:EmailAddress>
            user1@contoso.com 
          </t:EmailAddress>
        </t:Mailbox>
      </t:ToRecipients>
    </t:Message>
  </m:Items>
</m:CreateItem>
```

Or similar. What you want to do is not actually reply but forward an email.

Comment: Forward an email is a good idea but in server it will mark as FORWARD (icon).

Comment: So? Forwarding is literally what you are doing.

Comment: User should have opportunity to ReplyTo email and delete ToRecipients add Cc or Bcc and SEND. In result original sender hasn't receive email and in conversation it should mark as REPLY.

Look at this comment it works -  
"If you set the MessageDisposition to SaveOnly then save the message as a draft you can use UpdateItem to update the draft however you want and then use the SendItem operation to send the draft. – Glen Scales yesterday"